# How do I do a "deep" fetch join in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I don't think I will ever fully understand fetch joins.

I have a query where I'm attempting to eagerly "inflate" references down two levels.

That is, my `A` has an optional `Collection` of `B`s, and each `B` has either 0 or 1 `C`.  The size of the `B` collection is known to be small (10-20 tops).  I'd like to prefetch this graph.

`A`'s `B` relationship is marked as `FetchType.LAZY` and is optional.  `B`'s relationship to `C` is also optional and `FetchType.LAZY`.

I was hoping I could do:

```
SELECT a 
  FROM A a
  LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs // look, no alias; JPQL forbids it
  LEFT JOIN a.bs b // "repeated" join necessary since you can't alias fetch joins
  LEFT JOIN FETCH b.c // this doesn't seem to do anything
 WHERE a.id = :id
```

When I run this, I see that `A`s `B` collection is indeed fetched (I see a `LEFT JOIN` in the SQL referencing the table to which `B` is mapped).

However, I see no such evidence that `C`'s table is fetched.

How can I prefetch all `C`s and all `B`s and all `C`s that are "reachable" from a given `A`?  I can't see any way to do this.

Comment: What JPA provider do you use? There are hints available in EclipseLink exactly for this kind of functionality. Check out `eclipselink.join-fetch` and `eclipselink.batch` hints...

Comment: Thank you.  If I use `eclipselink.join-fetch`, it looks like I'm permitted to set only one attribute.  Is that correct?  For example, if I blow my `join-fetch` capital on `a.bs.c`, then if I also wanted to join fetch—say—`a.bs.d` I'd be out of luck.  Right?

Comment: Oh, this is interesting.  The EclipseLink documentation (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Query_Hints#Join_Fetch) does not say that duplicate query hint keys are possible but perhaps they are?  See this interesting link: https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/348

Comment: I can verify that multiple `eclipselink.join-fetch` hints do work. We use it heavily at work and generated SQL statements are correct.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any experience with this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408719?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JPA spec does not allow aliasing a fetch join, but some JPA providers do.

EclipseLink does as of 2.4.  EclipseLink also allow nested join fetch using the dot notation (i.e. "JOIN FETCH a.bs.c"), and supports a query hint "eclipselink.join-fetch" that allows nested joins (you can specify multiple hints of the same hint name).

In general you need to be careful when using an alias on a fetch join, as you can affect the data that is returned.

See,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/04/objects-vs-data-and-filtering-join.html

Comment: Thanks, @James; for various reasons we need to keep our JPQL standard, so it looks like the (string format) query hints for me.  Notably the use of a few of these results in a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408719 (also reported by someone else in 2010 here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=847970.  I'm leery of prefetching too deeply anyway, so perhaps this is oddly for the best. :-)

Comment: eclipselink.join-fetch is also working in eclipseLink 2.3:
.setHint("eclipselink.join-fetch", "a.bs.c")

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Hibernate (and this may be specific to it) and I've had success with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b 
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN a.bs b
LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs
LEFT JOIN FETCH b.c
WHERE a.id = :id
```

(Note the `b` in the select list).

This was the only way I found this would work for me, note that this returns `Object[]` for me and I then filter it in code like so:

```
(List<A>) q.getResultList().stream().map(pair -> (A) (((Object[])pair)[0])).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly JPQL, but you can achieve that in pure JPA with Criteria queries:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> q = cb.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
Root<MyEntity> root = q.from(MyEntity.class);
q.select(root);
Fetch bsFetch = root.fetch("b", JoinType.LEFT); //fetch b, property of MyEntity and hold fetch object
bsFetch.fetch("c", JoinType.LEFT); //fetch c, property of b
```

Support for this kind of nested fetch is vendor-specific (as JPA doesn't require them to do so), but both eclipselink and hibernate do support it, and this way your code remains vendor independant.

Answer (score 4):

> JPA does not allow nested join fetches, nor allow an alias on a join
>   fetch, so this is probably JPA provider specific.
>
> In EclipseLink, you can specify a query hint to perform nested join
>   fetches.
>
> You can't make it recursive in JPQL though, you could go only at best
>   n levels.  In EclipseLink you could use @JoinFetch or @BatchFetch on
>   the mapping to make the querying recursive.
>
> See, 
>   http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

Source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/570828/ORM/databases/Recursive-fetch-join-recursively-fetching