# EclipseLink:How to avoid additional sql query for nested left join

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
class A{
 @OneToMany
 private List<B> bs;
 ...
}

@Entity
class B{
 @OneToMany
 private List<C> cs;
 ...
}

@Entity
class C{
 ...
}
```

So I do the followin query:

```
SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs b LEFT JOIN b.cs
```

This code works, the only problem that A and B are read from database in one join query, but for reading C (LEFT JOIN b.cs) separate sql query is executed to read only C entities. How to read A,B,C in one sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA does not allow nested fetch joins but you can use the EclipseLink specific [left-join-fetch query hint](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_left-join-fetch.htm) to tell it you want the b.cs relationship fetched.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693590/496099)

edit:

use code

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a");
query.setHint("eclipselink.join-fetch", "a.bs.cs");
```

to have a->bs and bs->cs fetched and joined in the same query.

Comment: To tell the truth I can't understand what you mean. I know that you wrote. And by the way I use left-joint-fetch of eclipse link. The question is about using it isn't it?

Comment: Follow the links.  JPA does not support "A a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs b LEFT JOIN FETCH b.cs" which is what you would need to have all 3 entities fetched in the same query.  I pointed you at query hints that allow you to specify the fetch join on the b.cs relationship.  This is only slightly different from the question/answer I also linked to

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. What I did: 1) I added `<property name="eclipselink.left-join-fetch" value="true"/>` to persistence.xml 2)I added `query.setHint("eclipselink.LEFT_FETCH", "a.bs.cs");` to code 3) I corrected the query:`SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs  LEFT JOIN a.bs.cs`. The result is the exception:`The collection-valued path 'a.bs.cs' cannot be resolved to a valid association field`. What is my mistake?

Comment: I again did #1 and #2. And #3 now is:`SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs`. The result is the same as in my question - two queries.

Comment: The problem was solved via query.setHint("eclipselink.join-fetch", "a.bs.cs");

Comment: @Pavel_K could you please post an answer with the relevant code? Those comments are slightly confusing.

Comment: @payne Please, see Chris answer. He edited it.