# OpenJPA fetching entity with a lazy collection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities :

A:

```
class A {

 @Id
 Long id;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 List<B> listOfB;
}
```

and class B :

```
class B {

 @Id
 Long id;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 A a;
}
```

now in my spring data repo I'm creating a query like :

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM A a INNER JOIN a.listOfB b WHERE b.id = :id")
```

The problem is, that the query is executed and returns some A objects, but when I want to access the `listOfB` I'm getting a `NullPointerException` ...

```
A a = aRepository.findByOwnQuery(id);
a.getListOfB().size(); -> NullPointerException
```

Comment: Post your code, and post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: What code do you need ? There'are two entities with relation marked as lazy, and a query.

Comment: The code that causes the NPE.

Comment: so the list field is NULL, and the object "a" is presumably detached by that point so cannot fetch the field from the database. So fetch it before unmanaging the "a" object

Comment: @NeilStockton how ? I assume that when I'm joining the B class by `INNER JOIN a.listOfB b` I will have this list in result object ...

Comment: nope. that simply joins to form the query. "JOIN FETCH" is valid JPQL syntax ...

Answer (score -1):

The `NullPointerException` could be because you are fetching your child `listOfB` **Lazily** in your parent class `A`.

Try [`JOIN FETCH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate) like so

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.listOfB b WHERE b.id = :id")
```

Comment: With such contruction I'm getting the `ArgumentException` error `Encountered "b" at ... but expected: [",", "GROUP", "HAVING", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", "ORDER", "WHERE", <EOF>]`.

Comment: Are you sure this exception is because of the single change i suggested.?Because my change doesn't change the argument. It only changes the strategy to fetch to children. Please cross check.

Comment: Yep, because the previous query executes fine but returns null for the list.

Comment: The JPA spec doesn't allow use the 'b' defined on a fetch join clause within the query. You would have to create a separate join for the query to use in the where clause.

Comment: @Chris Thats something i didn't know. Can you post some reference.

Comment: I don't have a link to the spec, but the definition in "4.4.5.3 Fetch Joins" of jpa 2.1 does not include aliases.  Its posted in other answers elsewhere as well though https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693590/496099