# LEFT JOIN FETCH doesn´t work

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

How to fetch the Table3 (relationship OneToOne), using three levels of "LEFT JOIN" in JPA /Eclipselink 2.6.5?

This command don´t fetch it: (Wrong)

```
SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN FETCH t1.table2 t2
                         LEFT JOIN FETCH t2.table3
```

This command fetch it, but don´t keep first "LEFT": (Wrong)

```
SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN FETCH t1.table2
                         LEFT JOIN FETCH t1.table2.table3
```

This fetch it, but it is two levels only: (Unwanted)

```
SELECT t2 FROM Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN FETCH t2.table3
```

Table1:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "Id")
private Integer id;

@JoinColumn(name = "Table2", referencedColumnName = "Id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Table2 table2;
```

Table2:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "Id")
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "table2")
private Collection<Table1> table1Collection;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "table2")
private Table3 table3;
```

Table3:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "Id")
private Integer id;

@JoinColumn(name = "Table2", referencedColumnName = "Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Table2 table2;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the SQL generated from your various attempts? EclipseLink 2.4+ should support nested join fetches in JPQL https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693590/496099

Answer (score 1):

JPA/JPQL doesn't support nested fetch joins. To get around this, you can add a [query hint](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_left-join-fetch.htm#CHDEFDDC) to your query to tell it what you want joined using a left outer join. The [fetch-join](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_join_fetch.htm) query hint has a better example showing how it is used.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1", Table1.class);
query.setHint("eclipselink.LEFT_FETCH", "t1.table2");
query.setHint("eclipselink.LEFT_FETCH", "t1.table2.table3");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a right join between table1 and table2 here, so retry both of your first two examples using ´RIGHT JOIN` instead.