# How to cascade @JoinFetch in EclipseLink?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following model: Order has multiple items and items have multiple other children. It's a tree several levels deep.

I have EAGER loading on all `@OneToMany` together with `@JoinFetch` and LAZY loading on all `@ManyToOne` (to avoid additional queries in N+1 problem).

As per [How do I do a "deep" fetch join in JPQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680626/how-do-i-do-a-deep-fetch-join-in-jpql) I can use multiple query hints to presumably eager load the whole tree, however, I'd prefer to do this via annotations only.

Unfortunately, even with the whole tree annotated with `@JoinFetch`, it seems that the joins are performed 1 level deep only, leading to multiple queries instead of a single query for the whole tree.

These are the queries I can see being executed:

Order - left outer join on all children.

OrderItem - left outer join on all children.

...etc for all levels.

I can see `@JoinFetch` is working but it works only one level deep. What I'd like to achieve is a single query to load the whole tree.

While this one level deep load did help me speed up the calls more than 2x they are still suboptimal when loading a lot of entities at once since each entitiy means 5+ additional queries.

Is there a way to load the whole tree with annotations only or should I manually set multiple query hints to achieve this?

Answer by James Sutherland [here](https://coderanch.com/t/570828/databases/Recursive-fetch-join-recursively-fetching) does not seem to be true (about recursive working).

Comment: Have you tried `@EntityGraph`? This is the alternate to `join fetch` to eagerly load associations.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation I came to conclusion that annotations by (design?) only works 1 level deep. For full control I ditched the annotations and used query hints instead. Tracking [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532251).